# TFS 2017 Linked Parent Child Query - Filters between different Projects

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-query

I have a linked query where Parent is from one Project and linked child Query is from another project. I am able to create filters on project level. But how can i put filters between columns of Parent and linked child work item. Parent and child belong to different project .
example: Parent [WorkItemItem] = Child [WorkItemType]

[image: Linked Query]

Comment: Hi user3182464, this is not available at present. You could create a user voice here, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea Our PM will kindly review it, you could vote up and monitor it.

Comment: Hi user3182464, do you have any other concern about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

### In short. You can't.

But that answer is too short. So I have to add more so stackOverflow accepts this as an answer.